# Deploying multiple nodeJS on Digitalocean with Dokku

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean, dokku

I've tried to deploy two nodeJS apps on Digitalocean using a dokku droplet. I am using the "virtualhost naming" scheme but there is a problem.

My DNS configuration looks like this:

[image]

I have the main app and the admin app. I would expect to view the admin app when i visit app.example.com (I actually have a proper domain name) but I can see the same app when hitting example.com and app.example.com.

There is something wrong with nginx probably, but I don't know exactly what is going bad?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have noticed is that whichever app is installed first will be the one that example.com forwards to.

You are correct to attribute this behaviour to Nginx. I think it's due to it falling back to this config somehow when it doesn't detect a config for example.com

This dokku plugin (https://github.com/progrium/dokku/tree/master/plugins/nginx-vhosts) is responsible for rewriting the nginx.conf for each app every time it is deployed.

Nowadays it uses a template nginx.conf (https://github.com/progrium/dokku/blob/master/plugins/nginx-vhosts/templates/nginx.conf) although this is a fairly recent change so be sure your on a recent version.

You will end up with a Nginx config that looks like the following:

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name app.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I'm not currently sure why the above snippet results in the described behaviour. A work around is to setup your own nginx conf in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ with

```
server_name example.com;
```

but pointing to a holding page or whatever works for you.